# Android Http requests handler

Tags: android, httpclient

I have a problem with handling http requests with proxy on Android. I have a 3rd-party component which contacts a server and I need it to communicate via proxy. I can't set proxy in system. Handling of proxy for DefaultHttpClient should be fine but there is a problem with 3ed-party component which can't be accessed (don't have a source code) and can't set a proxy.

My questions are:
Is there any way to set proxy only for my application?
Or
Is there any way to create listener to http requests to handle proxy setting when calling for website?
Or
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if there was, if the third party component is not using system libraries, but their own, it would still not pick it up. Contact them and have them add proxy support, or at least make it clear what HTTP library they are using.

Comment: i am pretty sure they are using also DefaultHttpClient or HttpURLConnection. It's improbable they will add a proxy support, but i am sure they are using System libraries for communication.

Comment: In that case, there is not much you can do beside setting a system-wide proxy on supported devices. And you cannot do this from code without system/root privileges.